# Sign In User / Authenticate User with AWS Cognito

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I am trying to sign in a user server side on asp.net Core 2

I have registered a user and confirmed with a verification link but now I am struggling to sign that user into my application. It's a shame the documentation for c# is so poor!

User Pool Config:

**App Client:** Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH) - checked

Here's the code:

```
public async Task<bool> SignInUserAsync(CognitoUser user)
    {
        var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(),
            RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("eu-west-2"));

        try
        {
            var authReq = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest
            {
                AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH,
                UserPoolId = _poolId,
                ClientId = _clientId
            };
            authReq.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", user.Email);
            authReq.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", user.Password);

            AdminInitiateAuthResponse authResp = await provider.AdminInitiateAuthAsync(authReq);

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

The error that returns is `Missing Authentication Token` but I can't work out where the token needs to be set / has been given to me.

Is it something with my `AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient` settings or perhaps App client settings under the

`AWS > User Pools > App Intergration > App Client Settings`?

Answer (score 2):

[AdminInitiateAuth](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html) API is meant to be called from a back end which has access to developers IAM credentials. Since you are trying to call this with `AnonymousAWSCredentials`, you are getting `Missing Authentication Token` error.

Cognito User Pools does not yet have native support for C#. You should integrate Cognito User Pools in your C# app using the [hosted auth pages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html) instead of native API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your provider to:

```
var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient();
```